# Control Picker only shows controls on the Custom Control

Tags: xpages

I created a custom control with a custom property.  The property type is String and the Editor is Control Picker.

When I place the CC on an xPage and try to set the property the editor displays just fine, the only issue is that it seems to only list the controls on the CC and none of the controls on the xPage.

Is anyone else seeing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another editor in the list called the 'XPage Control ID Picker' this editor will list all the controls in the higher level XPage that the custom control is on.